# ¿Qué define el motivo final del cierre de una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, motivos-de-cierre

Tengo una inquietud... ¿Qué define el motivo de cierre cuando los *moderadores* eligen diferentes motivos?

¿Es por mayoría de votos? ¿y si todos los motivos tienen un voto cada uno se cierra por el motivo por el cual se reportó la pregunta?

Yo estaba revisando una pregunta, le di al motivo de que estaba **duplicada**, pero terminó cerrándose por **basada en opiniones**.

¿Por qué a veces coincide y otras no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando una pregunta se cierra como "off topic", aparecen todas las razones canónicas (es decir, no específicas del sitio) que acumularon al menos 2 votos o un voto de moderador diamantado.

Por ello, si se cierra con 5 votos, siendo el último de un moderador diamantado, pueden aparecer hasta 3 motivos diferentes.

Fuente: [Why does this question show 2 different close reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322205/209901), en la [respuesta de animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322208/209901).

En el caso que mencionas, (¿[esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/317588/83) según [la cola de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/189709)?) tu voto de duplicado debió ser el único.

Comment: Sí, era esa pregunta, perfecto. En la revisión yo no veo por cuál motivo voté para cerrar, pero adivinaste.

Comment: @ArtEze el historial de acciones de un usuario es una herramienta muy útil para investigar cosas así :)